# C++: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'LPSTR {aka char*}' [-Wwrite-strings] - warning. How to avoid?

Tags: c++, string

While compiling C++ code I get this warning:

> deprecated conversion from string constant to 'LPSTR {aka char*}'
>   [-Wwrite-strings]
>   &pi)) // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure.
>   
>      ^

Code is:

```
STARTUPINFO si;
memset(&si, 0, sizeof (STARTUPINFO));
si.cb = sizeof (STARTUPINFO);
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.wShowWindow = FALSE;

PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
memset(&pi, 0, sizeof (PROCESS_INFORMATION));

if (!CreateProcess("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\javaw.exe",
        " -jar install.jar", // Command line.
        NULL, // Process handle not inheritable.
        NULL, // Thread handle not inheritable.
        0, // Set handle inheritance to FALSE.
        CREATE_NO_WINDOW, // ON VISTA/WIN7, THIS CREATES NO WINDOW
        NULL, // Use parent's environment block.
        NULL, // Use parent's starting directory.
        &si, // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure.
        &pi)) // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure. //Warning comes from this line - variable &pi
{
    printf("CreateProcess failed\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to do something to avoid that (I mean not using - suppress warnings)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that the second parameter is of `CreateProcess` is of type `char*` but you are passing `const char*`. In other words, the second parameter of `CreateProcess` expects a modifiable buffer, but you are passing a non-modifiable literal.

Declare a modifiable string like this:

```
char cmdline[] = "-jar install.jar";
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd argument from CreateProcess() API should be as follows:

> _Inout_opt_  LPTSTR lpCommandLine,

now here you are directly passing the const char* value, hence you are getting the warning.

> char cmdline[] = " -jar install.jar";

should avoid this warning.

Comment: That doesn't solve the real problem that the function needs a modifiable buffer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: yes you are right :). I have corrected it.